# How to correctly handle Hikari connection pool with Doobie

Tags: postgresql, scala, connection-pooling, hikaricp, doobie

I've been using doobie (cats) to connect to a postgresql database from a scalatra application. Recently I noticed that the app was creating a new connection pool for every transaction. I eventually worked around it - see below, but this approach is quite different from that taken in the ['managing connections' section of the book of doobie](https://tpolecat.github.io/doobie-cats-0.4.2/14-Managing-Connections.html), I was hoping someone could confirm whether it is sensible or whether there is a better way of setting up the connection pool.

Here's what I had initially - this works but creates a new connection pool on every connection:

```
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
import doobie.hikari.hikaritransactor.HikariTransactor
import doobie.imports._

val pgTransactor = HikariTransactor[IOLite](
  "org.postgresql.Driver",
  s"jdbc:postgresql://${postgresDBHost}:${postgresDBPort}/${postgresDBName}",
  postgresDBUser,
  postgresDBPassword
)
// every query goes via this function
def doTransaction[A](update: ConnectionIO[A]): Option[A] = {
    val io = for {
      xa <- pgTransactor
      res <- update.transact(xa) ensuring xa.shutdown
    } yield res
    io.unsafePerformIO
}
```

My initial assumption was that the problem was having `ensuring xa.shutdown` on every request, but removing it results in connections quickly being used up until there are none left.

This was an attempt to fix the problem - enabled me to remove `ensuring xa.shutdown`, but still resulted in the connection pool being repeatedly opened and closed:

```
val pgTransactor: HikariTransactor[IOLite] = HikariTransactor[IOLite](
  "org.postgresql.Driver",
  s"jdbc:postgresql://${postgresDBHost}:${postgresDBPort}/${postgresDBName}",
  postgresDBUser,
  postgresDBPassword
).unsafePerformIO

def doTransaction[A](update: ConnectionIO[A]): Option[A] = {
    val io = update.transact(pgTransactor)
    io.unsafePerformIO
}
```

Finally, I got the desired behaviour by creating a `HikariDataSource` object and then passing it into the `HikariTransactor` constructor:

```
val dataSource = new HikariDataSource()
dataSource.setJdbcUrl(s"jdbc:postgresql://${postgresDBHost}:${postgresDBPort}/${postgresDBName}")
dataSource.setUsername(postgresDBUser)
dataSource.setPassword(postgresDBPassword)

val pgTransactor: HikariTransactor[IOLite] = HikariTransactor[IOLite](dataSource)

def doTransaction[A](update: ConnectionIO[A], operationDescription: String): Option[A] = {
  val io = update.transact(pgTransactor)
  io.unsafePerformIO
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
val xa = HikariTransactor[IOLite](dataSource).unsafePerformIO
```

and pass it to your repositories.
`.transact` applies the transaction boundaries, like `Slick`'s `.transactionally`.
E.g.:

```
def interactWithDb = {
  val q: ConnectionIO[Int] = sql"""..."""
  q.transact(xa).unsafePerformIO
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the response from Radu gets at the problem. The `HikariTransactor` (the underlying `HikariDataSource` really) has internal state so constructing it is a side-effect; and you want to do it once when your program starts and pass it around as needed. So your solution works, just note the side-effect.

Also, as noted, I don't monitor SO … try the Gitter channel or open an issue if you have questions. :-)